# On Ubuntu system number "7" just keeps typing automatically everywhere

Tags: linux, ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069855/the-symbol-automatically-starts-typing-repeatedly-everytime-in-linux-ubunt7777777

this kind of problem i'm facing like shown in the above link :-

1. repeated-key typing
2. Flickering on-boot

Comment: Change the keyboard

Comment: @RomeoNinov no it's not a hardware issue, i tried

Comment: Try to disconnect all possible devices and boot.

Comment: @VinayakS this almost certainly *is* a hardware issue. the question is which of your devices acts like a keyboard – it doesn't have to be a keyboard. Try removing the mouse, printers, external sound adapters, USB headphones…

Comment: Does it happen when booting from a Live Linux USB?

Comment: @harrymc - No , i'm using only linux on my HP laptop, there is no any dual booting too

Comment: try testing while booting from a Live Linux USB. If it still happens, then the problem is totally hardware.

Comment: @MarcusMüller- it doesn't happen continuously, i mean it keeps typing for around 2-3 min, then it stops for around 1 min and again it starts typing and the loop goes on

Comment: @MarcusMüller - tried, not yet resolved

Comment: It also doesn't stop when you immediately unplug the keyboard when it starts?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i tried this and it worked i.e disconnected the laptop keyboard and i'm using the physical keyboard. seems like it's a hardware issue, but **Flickering on-boot** problem still exist: any solution on that?

Comment: @harrymc i tried this and it worked i.e disconnected the laptop keyboard and using the physical keyboard. seems like it's a hardware issue, but **Flickering on-boot** problem still exist: any solution on that?

Comment: The only advice is to consult a repair-shop.